# How to conditionally show different UI in Jade?

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I have the following template:

extends layout

```
block content
  #wrapper
    #logo
      a(href='/')
        p #{title}
    #msg
      | hi #{user}
    #display
      #register
        ----A registration form here----
      #login
        ----A login form here-----

    include footer
```

If the user opens this page via `POST` and I use a token to decide if he is logged in like so:

```
exports.home = function(req, res) {
    // if user is not logged in, show both login and register forms
    if (typeof req.session.username == 'undefined') {
      res.render('home', { title: 'Online Coding Judge'});
    }
    // if user is logged in already, just say hi to him
    else {
      // what here???
    }
};
```

How do I show different things on the page depending on whether he logged in or not?

EDIT: A more realistic example would be to show an error message if there was a failed login in the same UI I would need to conditionally show an error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

EDIT: revised:

```
block content
  #wrapper
    #logo
      a(href='/')
        p #{title}
    if {user}
      #msg
        | hi #{user}
      #display
        #register
          ----A registration form here----
        #login
          ----A login form here----- 
    else 
       --- some other logic ---

    include footer
```

Comment: no, but that will leave out the rest of the UI. I want the entire page to remain ask it is, but instead of the forms, I want a hello message shown if the user is logged in.

Comment: guess I did not fully understand your question. In this case I guess you can use a simple if statement in your jade template as shown here: http://jade-lang.com/ or here: http://jade-lang.com/reference/ - Conditionals section

Comment: So in my case can what should I check for in my jade template? Like can I do `if #{user}` ?

Comment: I've edited the original answer to something that should be closer to what you want